# Facebook WebDriverAgent: How to run it without Xcode

Tags: ios, automation, webdriver, seetest

I want to run WebDriverAgent app without Xcode, like Seetest application which works independently

https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to run your automated test on iOS app with just SeeTest and without using Xcode?

If so then you need to do following steps:

1. Install SeeTest (Licensed or Trial version)
2. Create a DEF file for iOS device
3. Connect the iOS device to your computer
4. Record n play the steps required / Write your own code in the lang you are comfortable.
5. Execute the script.

Comment: I know with Seetest we can achieve it, and thats what I want to know how they achieved that, I am trying to implement the same